# Can I connect two independent clauses with the word "as?"

Tags: sentence-construction

> I have always been passionate about workers' rights, as I have had one of my parents injured while working in bad weather conditions.

I also do not know if I need the comma before the word "as."

Answer (score 1):

You can use *as* to mean *because*:
[Merriam-Webster *as*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as)
7 : for the reason that : because, since
*stayed home as she had no car*

However, the second clause includes the word "as", and it is no longer an independent clause. What it is depends on the interpretation of *as*. The dictionary above calls *as*, in this sense, a subordinating conjunction, which would make your second clause a subordinate clause. The modern interpretation of *because* in this sense is that it is a preposition, which would make your second clause the complement of a preposition, still not an independent clause

So your sentence is grammatical. I think the comma is optional in this use.

(A side note -
*... I have had one of my parents injured....*
is very wordy, and it can be misread. I suggest
*... one of my parents was injured ...*
That conveys the same meaning and can't be misread.)